# Taylor Expansion of a Summation

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to get a first order Taylor approximation of the following expression:
$$
\ln \left( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \pi_{a,j} \alpha_{a,j} \right)
$$
around the mean value $\overline{\pi \alpha}$.  Is this something that is feasible?

Comment: What is the independent variable? If you have an infinite sum it should be worthwhile approximating it with a finite sum, then calculating the Taylor Expansion of a function in $N$ variables.

Comment: @7raider7 I'm not sure what you mean by independent variable in this case. Both variables are terms that are affected by the index of summation.

Comment: So, you stop the sum at j=N, you have 2N variables? If so, the Taylor Expansion will be very complicated and the approximation will be to rough. I suggest to reformulate the problem and/or to give more details.